# representation of context free grammar relations

Tags: context-free-grammar

The production rules of a context free grammar are formalised as pairs, just a set of relations...

```
(α,β) ∈ R
```

where **α** is a non-terminal and **β** is either a terminal or a non-terminal.

thus S → A could be written as (S,A) ∈ R

But when parsing tagged natural language trees for probabilitic CFG's. Many of there rules are of the form:

```
NP → NNP POS
```

that is, the right hand side is not **always** a single terminal or non-terminal

Is there a way of formalising these production rules? As I can't see the relation method working...

unless they were perhaps more like (NP → NNP) → POS

Or is it that they are not the exact production rules,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A context-free grammar is defined by a four-tuple `(V, T, P, S)`:

- V   a set of non-terminal symbols
- T   a set of terminal symbols, disjoint from V
- P   a set of productions, each of which is a mapping `v → ω` where `v ∈ V` and **`ω ∈ (V ⋃ T)*`**
- S   an element of `V`, the start symbol

Technically, you could derive `V` and `T` from `P`. However, everyone does roughly as above (with some variation of names, and occasionally using `V` and `V ⋃ T` as primitives instead of `V` and `T`).

The important point (in bold above) is that the right-hand side of a production is not "a terminal or a non-terminal" but rather "an element of `(V ⋃ T)*`". If you couldn't expand a non-terminal into more than one symbol, your language would only consist of single-element strings.